# Ubuntu 12.10 trouble Installing Netbeans 7.3 and JAVA ME 32 bit

Tags: java, netbeans

I tried CHMOD, updating, simple terminal line commands and nothing seems to work. When I try install NetBeans 7.3 the screen is blank and if I try to do something it gives me the error that states the application will close and asks for a force quit option and says all progress will be lost. 
Any ideas? I have been to both the NetBeans forums and asked as well as the Java boards which directed me back to NetBeans forum page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the [netbeans forum](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic54366.html):**

> *Post subject:*
>   Setting Up Netbeans for java ME installation question
>
> *Reply:*
>   If you use the packages from netbeans.org then you can install different NetBeans versions side-by-side. Newer version even
>   try to import settings and plugins from the previous version.

*By markiewb*

Comment: its not solved though. the required installation is unzipped but not available to add as a platform, nor has JAVA ME been made available through the same means; by using the tools menu to 'add NB platform' and 'add java me platform'the IDE doesnt see the files so I cant add them with the feature

Comment: Well, if you think that you can wait for other answer *solving* your issue, then it's ok.

Comment: what choice do I have? I need version 7.3 to use java ME and I cant upgrade the version I have. I answered the question before trying to see if it worked because it seemed like a no brainer. 4 days later....

Comment: as it turns out, I had a second look at the NetBeans forum and i found this,

Comment: Am 15.03.13 15:33, schrieb johnye2e: 
Quote:
Hi guys, 


I have Netbeans 7.2.1 installed, and I was just wondering why is it showing that it's up to date (Help -> Check for updates), even though Netbeans 7.3 is released? And is there a way to automatically update to 7.3? 

No, deinstall 7.2.1. and install 7.3. 

--

Comment: The IDE should be removed and reinstalled with the desired version as it seems that this is the only way to make this work. There doesnt seem to be alot of interest on the Netbean boards to confirm or deny this.